# R how to convert UTF-8 code like <U+9600><U+524D> back to Chinese characters

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

When I used `read.csv` to read files containing Chinese characters with option `encoding = "UTF-8"`, I get these mysterious codes.

By a little comparing, I realize they can one to one match Chinese characters, but how can I convert them back to Chinese characters  in R.

For example, `<U+9600>` and `<U+524D>` are respectively `"阀"` and `"前"`.

Comment: Writing `\U9600` in the R console will give you the symbol you wrote, 阀. Can you try to replace the `<U+9600>` by `\U9600` with `gsub`?

Comment: Is the file encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: What is the OS you use? If it's Windows, the handling of UTF-8 is sort of shaky.

Comment: `\U9600` does work for me. My OS is windows 7. The file is encoded as UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your locale settings to get the chinese character, for exmpale:

```
x <- "阀"
print(x) will result in ##[1] "<U+9600>"
```

Saving your locale settings in a an object as backup so that we can undo the locale settings as earlier

```
oldloc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")
```

Change the locale by putting "**en_US.UTF-8**" as second argument:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8")
print(x) ###The result is now [1] "阀"
```

You can also try locale `zh_CN.UTF-‌​8`, it worked for me as well. In case you mess anything up then you can use below to get to the previous state:

```
Sys.setlocate("LC_CYTPE",oldloc)
```

I just realised while going to the comments that OP is working on Windows machine, The above command works very good with my Mac sierra, but produces warning as below on windows 7 machine:

> ```
> Warning message:
> In Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8") :
>   OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored
> ```

However, to solve above problem on windows, I used stringi's function `stri_trans_general` like below, this solves the problem and print the required Chinese characters

`stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "zh")`

**Output**:

```
> stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "zh")
[1] "阀"
```

You can visit [**here**](http://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php) to see the locales for different regions.

Comment: Hi do you now a way to convert character '<U+4ECA><U+65E5><U+4E0D><U+8C03>' back to original chinese?